# Is there iOS support NFC ISO 14443-3 Type-B

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc

I can see the official document for CoreNFC. I know it support ISO 14443 type A and B modulation. The option for detecting ISO 7816-compatible and MIFARE tags.

But I don't understands is it support ISO 14443-3 Type-B.

What is the different between "ISO 14443" and "ISO 14443-3 Type-B"?

Is it support ISO 14443 type A and B modulation include support ISO 14443-3 Type-B?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the ISO 14443 Standard are that if the device uses Type-A modulation (ISO 14443-2A, ISO 14443-2 Type A, etc many different ways of writing it)

See http://emutag.com/iso/14443-2.pdf

Then it has to use Type-A for the anti-collision level in ISO 14443-3 (ISO 14443-3A, ISO 14443-3 Type A, etc many different ways of writing it)

http://emutag.com/iso/14443-3.pdf

And the same goes for Type-B

The modulation Type determines which anti-collision process is needed when the bit patterns of the modulated RF signal of multiple Tags combines to be 100%

So if a device supports Type-B Modulation ISO 14443-2B then it has to support ISO 14443-3B (otherwise there is no point supporting Type B modulation)

And as iOS support NFC Type 4 cards (accessed by ISO 7816) and these can be either Type-A or Type-B (using both part 2 and part 3 ISO 14443), then it is highly like that it supports "ISO 14443-3 Type-B"